# Cross referencing a pid of a process accessing a file to the process that called for it

Tags: linux, process, pid

I have set up auditd on a system and had it track some configuration files of an app. I expect that the app itself will access those files so I would like to know when a file was accessed by the app and when something else accessed it.

My first approach at this was to cross reference the pid or ppid I'm getting from auditd with the pid of the app, which is held in its pid file.

However, the processes are different, and the parent of both is 1 (init), which means nowhere up the process tree they cross.

Tracking the process of the artifact a bit with `strace` I see that it calls for a clone and gets the process id of the one caught by auditd.

My question is, other than constantly tracking the original process for clones, is there any way to know that a cloned process was originated from another? Or even better, is there any way to get that info directly from auditd in a reliable way?

Answer (score -1):

Do you need to do this in real time or are you looking for a static report? If you're looking for a static report try:

```
ausearch -i --file /your/file/path
```

-i translates PIDs/UIDs.

Comment: New to the forum, not immediately clear as to why this was down voted. If the answer isn't relevant to the question knowing why would be useful in helping provide information that is.