# How to get a list of files accessed by a subprocess?

Tags: python, linux

I have a process that I am trying to move from a linux box A to linux box B. The problem is that the process is a blackbox (binary) that accesses files on A's file system. However, since B is a new box, the binary complains about missing files on B's filesystem that used to exist on A's filesystem when run on B.

The way I've been doing this migration is to run the binary, see which files it complains about (say /random/path/to/file.csv), then I would generate the directory on B's filesystem: /random/path/to/file.csv, then rerun this and see the next file that the binary complains about.

Now obviously this is taking a ridiculous amount of time. To make it worse, the binary takes a really long time to start, so each "run" is burning through hours.

My question is, is there some way to run this binary on Server A in some kind of encapsulation, say as a subprocess in a python script, and log which files it access? This would help me to automate the process of syncing the relevant parts of Server A's filesystem with Server B.

Comment: You're already using its output to determine what to copy over, and you've already hit on the idea of Subprocess; did you try running it that way and parsing its output? Seems like a reasonable first step.

Comment: @kungphu By using its output, I mean that when the binary crashes and I look at the core dump, I see it failed to read file "xyz". I then add add the file to the file system, then rerun again to see which next file it will crash to. I am hoping for a solution that would run the entirety of the binary on A, then report to me all the paths that was accessed by the binary on A.

Comment: This looks like a similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956245/cross-referencing-a-pid-of-a-process-accessing-a-file-to-the-process-that-called. Unfortunately it never got a much responses. But given that it was posted about 3 years ago, if you get in touch with the author of the question, you might find something useful.

Comment: Also, sometimes the binary would access /same/path/to/file1.csv, /same/path/to/file2.csv, /same/path/to/file3.csv. I would then spot this, and sync all of /same/path/to directory. Doing this programatically would mean that the binary would crash n times if there are n files that are missing in a directory.

Comment: Is the core dump not in a predictable location? It's not really clear what the problem would be with reading the output, whether you're getting it from stdout, a dump file, etc. Not sure how you'd expect to add those on the fly, re: multiple files to sync; seems like this is why it'd help to script it, if it's crashing any time a single file is missing. You could also just assume all files in a directory are necessary, unless that would be a prohibitive amount of storage/transfer.

Comment: To your original question, maybe running the daemon with [strace](https://linux-audit.com/monitor-file-access-by-linux-processes/) on the original box would work? It's not something I've used personally.

Comment: @kungphu What I am looking to automate is this: Run the binary on A. Generate a report of all files accessed by the binary on A's file system. What you're suggesting is to automate this: Run the binary on B. Read the core programatically and parse the missing file. Sync the file. Repeat and rerun the binary until it terminates successfully. The difference is that what I am looking for would only need the binary to run once, what you're suggesting it would rerun it N times, where N is the number of missing files. Add to this that each run takes almost 20 minutes, you need 20*N minutes.

Comment: Will `ausearch -p` (process-id) help in tracking which files are being accessed? (`ausearch -f`).